# Html rendering issue when parsed through div.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am relatively new to Javascript and jquery so please forgive if this may be silly.
I am making a html content(Document) reader which would run in a browser.

```
<div id="documentContainer">
    <div class="dcIconsListTop" id="annotationIconsDiv"></div>
    <div id="documentContainerScroll" style="padding:0px;width:100%;overflow:auto;margin:0px;"></div>
</div>
```

and inserting the actual content in the `div.load`

```
this.iframe = jQuery('<div id = "documentframe" width="744px" scrolling="no" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" src="about:blank"></div>');
jQuery("#iframeContainerScroll").append(this.iframe);
jQuery('#documentframe').load(contentURL, function() {
    jQuery(this).trigger("create");
    //obj.iFrameOnLoad();
});
```

The problem is the actual document is not getting rendered properly.Basic inline styling is shown in the browser but some html tags are not apearing as expected in the browser(Although the tags are getting passed to the browser correctly)

The html content:::

```
<p><strong>This is bold</strong></p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
<p><em>this is italic</em><strong> <br></strong></p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">This is und<strong><br></strong></span></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p>Detailed session recording serves a wide variety of purposes:</p>
<div class="blockquote">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p>It trains students to recall the details of their interactions with clients-the verbal and nonverbal content that makes up the interaction.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p>It trains students to be aware of emotional undertones of the interaction, which will provide clues to the motivational state experienced by the client, and to transference phenomena.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p>It encourages students to develop insight into their own emotional reactions to clients and counseling situations (countertransference) so that they will not act out on their feelings without awareness.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p>It provides a framework to track the helping process, identify what skills were or were not applied, and clarify the purposes and efficacy of their interventions.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p>It develops the ability to communicate insights, thoughts, and feelings in written form.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p>It provides a framework for the instructor and student to collaboratively evaluate the training process individually, as the basis for class discussion, in students' casework, or in practicum classes. Students may also refer to recorded material in their theoretical papers, linking it to their practice.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<h2 style="clear: both;" class="title"><a target="_blank" name="ID0EKB"></a></h2>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

PLEASE PLEASE help!

Also if anyone could suggest me a different way to do this i would really appreciate..
Background:
1)I started with building an iframe for the actual content because i dint want the content scripts and the player(Buttons around the content) scripts to mix.But that was a not good practice because i could not control the inner content html so as to increase/decrease font etc...
2)So i am searching for a different way to do this.Can anyone suggest?

Comment: You should post the rendered HTML. Use the browser developer tools to capture the actual DOM tree and post it, so se can see the differences ... though you're being a bit vague about what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Have you heard of fiddle?

Comment: So, if you put the content hardcoded into `#iframeContainerScroll` without `.load()` (copy-pasting it), does it shows properly?